# Redirect Cloud Foundry streaming logs to log providers like papertrail or others

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to send logs out to an external logging platform using the following command:

```
cf cups activity-tracker -l https://HOST:PORT
```

I am assuming activity-tracker that is created by above command will send all activity or access logs automatically to an externally exposed API. But so far I am not seeing results popup in papertrail, I also tried others like splunk. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to send application "logs" to papertrail?  Activity Tracker is used for audit "events": https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/270/events/list_all_events.html.  Or is it your intent to stream these events to a 3rd party service?

Comment: @VanStaub Intent is to stream audit logs to 3rd party service.

Comment: Got it. Let me check if this is an available option.  I think the question should be updated to be specific to Activity Tracker events rather than "Cloud Foundry stream logs".  The latter is supported via a syslog drain https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/hosting-services/cloud-foundry/#set-up-cloud-foundry-drain.

Comment: @VanStaub That is weird as above command will create an activity tracker, so one will assume it will be sending all activity tracker logs as well right?

Comment: It's true that "cf cups activity-tracker -l <url>" creates a service named _activity-tracker_ with a syslog URL. Cloud Foundry "User-provided service instances enable developers to stream applications logs."  I'll post steps to do so as an answer.  But it's not creating an instance of the IBM service called [Activity Tracker](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/activity-tracker), which is what's receiving and storing IBM Cloud events.

Answer (score 0):

The process to syslog drain to papertrail is documented [here](https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/hosting-services/cloud-foundry/#set-up-cloud-foundry-drain). This will send application and Cloud Foundry related logs to papertrail.

```
ibmcloud cf cups my-logs -l syslog-tls://logsN.papertrailapp.com:XXXXX
ibmcloud cf bind-service <appname> my-logs
ibmcloud cf restart <appname>
```

The is no mechanism to stream the events in real-time from Activity Tracker to another endpoint. The closest solution would be downloading events and piping them to a 3rd party using a program. The [Downloading Events](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker/how-to/manage_events_api/downloading_events_api.html#downloading_events_api) documentation may help you to do so.

Comment: I just want to send audit logs. The first line of the above commands you mentioned creates an activity tracker. Will just that be enough to send audit logs to papertrail?

Comment: I dont have any apps right now. Just want audit logs to flow to papertrail.

Comment: Yep, I understand the need. Updated the answer, unfortunately, there's no way to do this at present.

Comment: So just doing the first line(ibmcloud cf cups my-logs -l syslog-tls://logsN.papertrailapp.com:XXXXX) will not send any audit logs over to papertrail? Is there any other way to do this currently?